# issues when use a timer to save List<class> into DB , and the List is writing by multi threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

In main thread ,  I define a List, and create a timer with interval 1 second , and start three tasks which write data into the List .

Timer thread 's mission is check if List 's count > 100 , if true , then save this List into sql server DB .

here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

namespace MultiThreadInserDataIntoList
{
public class CommandDetail
{
    public string sessionIP { get; set; }
    public string sessionID { get; set; }
    public string commandName { get; set; }
    public DateTime cmd_recv_time { get; set; }
    public DateTime cmd_reply_time { get; set; }
    public string cmd_content { get; set; }
    public string reply_content { get; set; }
    public string err_reason { get; set; }
 }

class Program
{
    static System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    static List<CommandDetail> CommandDetailList = new List<CommandDetail>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff(CommandDetailList));
        Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff(CommandDetailList));
        Task task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff(CommandDetailList));
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(JobCallBack), null, 0, 1000);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    //
    static void doStuff(object o1)
    {
        List<CommandDetail> typed = (List<CommandDetail>)o1;
        CommandDetail cst = new CommandDetail { cmd_recv_time = DateTime.Now, cmd_reply_time = DateTime.Now, reply_content = "111", cmd_content="111", commandName="GETNAP", sessionID="111", sessionIP="111" };

        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            typed.Add(cst);
            //Console.WriteLine("add one row to list");
        }
    }
    //
    static void JobCallBack(object state)
    {
        if (CommandDetailList.Count > 100)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-DQPC13K;Initial Catalog=SmalllSmartBilling;Integrated Security=True;"))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
                    comm.CommandText = "sp_InsertRequestReply";
                    comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    comm.CommandTimeout = 300;


                    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@TVP",
                        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
                        Value = GetDataTableParam(CommandDetailList)
                    });

                    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@result",
                        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                        Size = 4
                    });

                    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@errormsg",
                        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                        Size = 1000
                    });

                    int iEffect = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("this time total insert {0} rows",iEffect);
                }
                catch (Exception uep)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }   //using

            //clear
            Console.WriteLine("before clear,List have {0} rows", CommandDetailList.Count);
            CommandDetailList.Clear();


        }   // if > 100
    }

    //
    static DataTable GetDataTableParam(List<CommandDetail> People)
    {
        //define the table and rows (the rows match those in the TVP)
        DataTable peopleTable = new DataTable();
        peopleTable.Columns.Add("Session_IP", typeof(string));
        peopleTable.Columns.Add("Session_ID", typeof(string));
        peopleTable.Columns.Add("CommandName", typeof(string));

        peopleTable.Columns.Add("Request_Recv_Time", typeof(DateTime));
        peopleTable.Columns.Add("Request_reply_Time", typeof(DateTime));

        peopleTable.Columns.Add("Request_Content", typeof(string));
        peopleTable.Columns.Add("Reply_Content", typeof(string));
        peopleTable.Columns.Add("Err_Reason", typeof(string));


        foreach (CommandDetail p in People)
        {
            // add a row for each person
            DataRow row = peopleTable.NewRow();
            //row["clsCarrierID"] = p.clsCarrierID;
            //row["clsis_supplier"] = p.clsis_supplier;
            row["Session_IP"] = p.sessionIP;
            row["Session_ID"] = p.sessionID;
            row["CommandName"] = p.commandName;

            row["Request_Recv_Time"] = p.cmd_recv_time;
            row["Request_reply_Time"] = p.cmd_reply_time;
            row["Request_Content"] = p.cmd_content;
            row["Reply_Content"] = p.reply_content;
            row["Err_Reason"] = p.err_reason;

            peopleTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return peopleTable;


    }

    //
  }
}
```

My original idea is when find List count reach 100 , save it into db and clear List .  above test  code each thread write 300 list item into List , but only 850 save into DB . I  know this maybe in the last exam , List count is not enough 100 , so do not save .

but still exist another problem :  please check the output picture :

[image]

seems thread concurrent insert item into List between List save into DB and List clear ,have any way avoid it ?  or that is my total design error , have other better method to save a List which write by multi thread into DB ,without losing any List Item .

Regards

Comment: why use multi-thread to insert database?

Comment: hi , multi -thread to insert item into List , in main thread have a timer to check if this List reach for example 100 count , if so , then save it into DB

Comment: I think it's bad to do db operations in timer.

Comment: maybe yes , I also search better method

Comment: Use one of the thread safe collections from the [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.

Comment: I  have try it just now , seems ConcurrentBag<int> this type  do not have clear() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a queue.   Every time the queue reaches 100, remove 100 items from the queue and write them to the database ( meanwhile your threads will still be adding to the queue )

`ConcurrentQueue` is suitable for this.

```
static ConcurrentQueue<CommandDetail> _commandDetails = new ConcurrentQueue<CommandDetail>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff(_commandDetails));
    Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff(_commandDetails));
    Task task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff(_commandDetails));
    var _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(JobCallBack), null, 0, 1000);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void JobCallBack(object state)
{
    const int chunk = 100;
    if (_commandDetails.Count >= chunk)
    {
        var items = _commandDetails.Take(chunk);
        Remove(_commandDetails, chunk);
        Console.WriteLine($"DB call with {chunk} Items");
    }
}

private static void Remove(ConcurrentQueue<CommandDetail> q, int count)
{
    CommandDetail commandDetail;
    Enumerable.Range(1, count).ToList().ForEach(n => q.TryDequeue(out commandDetail));
}
static void doStuff(ConcurrentQueue<CommandDetail> typed)
{
    var cst = new CommandDetail();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        typed.Enqueue(cst);                
    }
}
```

Comment: hi  ,  how to remove 100 item of ConcurrentQueue atomic

Comment: from your description you don't need atomic remove of 100 items, you just need threadsafe adds and removes